# Creating a Virtual Machine copy of SharePoint 2010 Server

Tags: sharepoint-server, virtual-machine

Is it possible to create a Virtual Machine copy of a SharePoint 2010 server? Would the copy lose any functions? Are there any guides to do this?

I am running Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because it is a copy of the system at a specific state so whatever state that system was in when you created the virtual copy it will be the same when you instantiate it. The only gotchas are networks and load balancing if you have that type of setup and also all servers in the farm would have to have a virtual image created at the same time.